# illegal_argument_exception no mapping found for field in search

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am learning ElasticSearch using the 5.1 version. I have an index "mycontent" and a type "simpledocument". I am running into an error "illegal_argument_exception no mapping found for field" while trying to check the suggest/completion feature on the simpledocument type. The details are below:

```
GET _search
{
  "suggest":{
    "my-suggestion":{
      "prefix":"ap",
      "completion":{
        "field":"suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the response:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": ".kibana",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "no mapping found for field [suggest]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
......
```

The mapping does have the suggest field in it:

```
GET _mapping/simpledocument

{
  "mycontent": {
    "mappings": {
      "simpledocument": {
        "properties": {
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "path": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample document:

```
GET mycontent/simpledocument/7
{
  "_index": "mycontent",
  "_type": "simpledocument",
  "_id": "7",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Suggested Document",
    "description": "this document does not contain a lot of content. Mainly used to test the suggest feature.",
    "tags": [
      "suggest",
      "document"
    ],
    "suggest": [
      "and",
      "design",
      "api"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can somebody please help me figure out my mistake? Why does it say "no mapping found" when the mapping is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GET _search` will search all **index**, as the **error**, it's saying the index `.kibana` doesn't have the `suggest` field, as your  `GET _mapping/simpledocument`, the **suggest** field should only exist in `simpedocument` **index type**.

so maybe you need to do it like:

```
GET mycontent/simpledocument/_search
{
  "suggest":{
    "my-suggestion":{
      "prefix":"ap",
      "completion":{
        "field":"suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```