# django_elasticsearch_dsl 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Field [name] is not a completion suggest field'

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to perform Completion with django-elasticsearch-dsl. So i created the following document:

```
@registry.register_document
class QuestionDocument(Document):
    name = fields.TextField(
        attr='title',
        fields={
            'suggest': fields.Completion(),
        }
    )

    class Index:
        name = 'questions'

    class Django:
        model = QuestionModel
        fields = ['text', 'title']
```

And to perform completion with elasticsearch:

```
matched_questions = list(QuestionDocument.search().suggest("suggestions", word, completion={'field': 'name.suggest'}).execute())
```

But the following exception occurs saying that no mapping exists for name.suggest:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'no mapping found for field [name.suggest]')
```

What am i doing wrong here? Is my approach correct or should i be doing this in a complete different way?

Comment: Are you certain that you deleted your index prior to running your code? What do you get when running `curl -XGET questions`?

Comment: Have you seen this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728211/illegal-argument-exception-no-mapping-found-for-field-in-search

Comment: @Mohammad hp, have you found a solution to this, please?